# Writing multiple letters in french using the same latex file

Tags: letters

Is this the way to write multiple letters in french using the same latex file?

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\title{First document}
\author{Randy}
\date{September 2022}

\signature{Randy}

\address{Plateau de Moulon \\
  3 rue Joliot-Curie \\
  F-91192 Gif-sur-Yvette Cedex}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Directeur Général de CentraleSupélec}

  \opening{Monsieur Romain Soubeyran,}

  CentraleSupélec est un Établissement public à caractère scientifique,
  culturel et professionnel (EPSCP) constitué sous la forme d’un Grand
  Établissement, relevant de la tutelle conjointe du Ministère de
  l’Enseignement supérieur, de la Recherche et de l'Innovation et du
  Ministère de l’Économie, de l'Industrie et du Numérique.
  
  \closing{Je vous prie d’agréer, \\
    l’expression de mes salutations distinguées,}

  \signature{Randy}

\end{letter}

%%-----------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\begin{letter}{Directeur Général de CentraleSupélec}

  \opening{Monsieur Romain Soubeyran,}

  CentraleSupélec est un Établissement public à caractère scientifique,
  culturel et professionnel (EPSCP) constitué sous la forme d’un Grand
  Établissement, relevant de la tutelle conjointe du Ministère de
  l’Enseignement supérieur, de la Recherche et de l'Innovation et du
  Ministère de l’Économie, de l'Industrie et du Numérique.
  
  \closing{Je vous prie d’agréer, \\
    l’expression de mes salutations distinguées,}

  \signature{Randy}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are in France, are you sure you want the `letterpaper` option.

Comment: I use letter if I am writing a letter.   I do not change setup because of country, but this is just me.

Comment: `letterpaper` has nothing to do with writing a letter, it's a paper format. If you are in France I seriously doubt your printer uses letterpaper-sized sheets. You most likely have A4.

Comment: Yes, but I do not actually send physical letters much.  The question is a different one.  It is about the use of `\begin{letter}`.

Comment: When I try your MWE it produces one pdf with two pages and a letter on each page. Is this not what you want? What do you want to change about this output?

Comment: Ok, I can write multiple letters in one latex file - starting each one with `\begin{letter}{''recipient''}` and ending with `\end{letter}`.